# Geoserver : how to use getlegendgraphic to avoid duplicate symbols in legend because of rules

Tags: geoserver, symbology, legend, mviewer

I am currently doing a master's internship in a town hall. I am working on improving the interactive map of the municipality where I work; it uses the Geoserver platform to host the layers and their style, and uses the mviewer package for online publishing.
Since a few days, I encounter a number of difficulties on the map. I'm still starting on geoserver and interactive mapping in general.

The first issue is the following: I made sure for a given layer that the symbology adapts to the map according to a range of scales. For example, for a scale between 10000 and 50000 (using min and maxscaledenominator), the symbol has a size of 50m on map. So I used the "rule" property for each condition. But, the problem is that my icons have been published several times in the graphic legend; basically, the same symbol appears several times for a different size, related to each  which gives a different size for each scale. So I would like to know if there is a way to have only one symbol represented instead of all. Here is the problem in picture :
[image]
And this is the code of the layer's style :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
     <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <NamedLayer>
      <Name>Canisite</Name>
      <UserStyle>
      <Title>Canisite</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
      <Rule>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <MinScaleDenominator>100</MinScaleDenominator>
      <PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
        <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource
              xlink:type="simple"
              xlink:href="https://extranet.ville-houilles.fr/mviewer/png_test/dogd.png" />
            <Format>image/png</Format>
          </ExternalGraphic>
          <Size>30</Size>
          </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
          </Rule>

          <Rule>
              <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator>
              <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
              <PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
               <Graphic>
                <ExternalGraphic>
                 <OnlineResource
              xlink:type="simple"
              xlink:href="https://extranet.ville-houilles.fr/mviewer/png_test/dogd.png" />
                 <Format>image/png</Format>
                </ExternalGraphic>
                <Size>70</Size>
               </Graphic>
              </PointSymbolizer>
              </Rule>        

             <Rule>
             <MaxScaleDenominator>20000</MaxScaleDenominator>
             <MinScaleDenominator>10000</MinScaleDenominator>
              <PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
                <Graphic>
                 <ExternalGraphic>
                   <OnlineResource
              xlink:type="simple"
              xlink:href="https://extranet.ville-houilles.fr/mviewer/png_test/dogd.png" />
                   <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>150</Size>
                 </Graphic>
                </PointSymbolizer>
               </Rule>     

               <Rule>
               <MaxScaleDenominator>150000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                <MinScaleDenominator>20000</MinScaleDenominator>
                <PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
                  <Graphic>
                   <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource
              xlink:type="simple"
              xlink:href="https://extranet.ville-houilles.fr/mviewer/png_test/dogd.png" />
                     <Format>image/png</Format>
                   </ExternalGraphic>
                   <Size>220</Size>
                  </Graphic>
                 </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
              </FeatureTypeStyle>
              </UserStyle>
              </NamedLayer>
              </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Apparently, you can use a parameter called GetlegendGraphic, but I don't understand how it works, nor how to insert the links generated in the code.
Another problem concerns the superposition of the layers: is there a solution so that, necessarily, the point layers are displayed over the linear and surface layers? Because these first are found hidden by these last ones when a user interacts and selects first a point, then a surface or line ... I tried the option of a group layer and sorted all the layers out, which gave me a good result in previsualization in "openlayers" in Geoserver, but they seems to be no way to publish as the official map, the group layer I created...

I'm aware that it's a lot of problems like that, a bit poorly formulated ^^, and I'm waiting for your answers, my level on geoserver just needs to improve! If needed, I can also give you the html and xml codes used for mviewer linked to the map.

Comment: please don't include screenshots of code or xml, it is almost impossible to read (especially for users on mobile devices).

Comment: Edited (sorry I didn't get how to insert code lines in a message)

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution @IanTurton ; I saw this question a few days ago (I knew my problem had already been asked); but I don't understand how to get links by using GetlegendGraphic, I understand the parameters in the link and what has to be added, but I don't understand how to get the link, nor where to insert it in a code...

Comment: then please edit your question to focus on the part that you need help on, referring to the other question if need be

Comment: Done, I hope it is more precise for you

Answer (score 1):

A GetLegendGraphic without any context will render all available rules. You can pass the "SCALE" parameter to only render rules active at a given scale denominator.
See documentation here: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#getlegendgraphic